# Getters and setters and container objects (ArrayList, HashMap, etc)

Tags: java, encapsulation, getter-setter

Say you have a domain class that has an ArrayList attribute. What is the best practise when writing getters and setters for this type of instance (to avoid it being modified)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public List getList() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this, even if you point to where unmodifiable lists are explained?

Answer (score 2):

Return a List that is unmodifiable using the `Collection.unmodifiableList()` method:

[Collections - Collection.unmodifiableList()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Collections.unmodifiableList()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29). There are equivalents for the other major collections types.

Answer (score 1):

lweller's response is the what I would do in most cases, but it does throw an `UnsupportOperationException` which you may not want to deal with.  In that case you might want to consider declaring a composite class, like `UnmodifiableList`, which contains a `List` of your choosing and exposes all the methods you want to support excluding those that would modify the list.  This, of couse, would no longer be type compatible with the `Collection` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best practice is to move the code that operates on the list into the domain class. Possibly add a domain class that represents the sequence in a way appropriate to the domain.

If you are desperate to expose the list, then there is a choice:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Thing>(things));
    // Bit big - shame there isn't a single method and class to do this.

return new ArrayList<Thing>(things);
    // Do you really want to see client code modifying the list?

return Collections.unmodifiableList(things);
    // Client may expecting a snapshot, modifications to the original will mess up.
```

Note if the elements of the list are mutable, you might want to do something about those too.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider making an immutable snapshot of the list.

```
public List getList() {
    ArrayList copy = new ArrayList(this.list);
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(copy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a naming convention where

```
listXXX();
```

gives you a read-only list.
There might be setters/getters in addition to that with the proper access modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html) ImmutableList class.  Your getter should then follow the form:

```
public ImmutableList<T> getMyList() {
  ImmutableList.copyOf(myList);
}
```

The advantage of guava over the Collections.unmodifiableList is that it reveals to the client that your colllection is immutable in the method signature, so there's very little chance of people mistakenly trying to add something to the collection.